# Segmentation fault: 11 after back-porting TensorFlow script from Python 3 to Python 2

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

After having created a TensorFlow 1.4 model for Python 3, I have now found that Google Cloud ML Engine currently only has support for Python 2.7.

Back-porting my Python 3 code at first seemed simple enough: Some scripts still work as expected when I replace their shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` with `#!/usr/bin/env python`. `python -V` reports `2.7.10` in my (macOS) environment.

Yet one script does not react so gracefully. When I run it now, it produces a `Segmentation fault: 11` without any previous warnings or other diagnostic output.

How can I find out about the root cause, so that I know what else to change to make also that script palatable to Python 2?

**UPDATE** The segmentation fault apparently occurs during a call to `session.run(get_next)`, where `get_next` is obtained from a `tf.data.Iterator` as follows:

```
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
get_next = iterator.get_next()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here: one is about Python 3 support and the other is about the segfault.

**Python 3 Support**
CloudML Engine now supports Python 3, via the 'pythonVersion' field when submitting jobs (see the [API reference docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.jobs#TrainingInput)).

If you are using `gcloud` you will need to create a config file like this (let's name it `config.yaml`):

```
trainingInput:
  pythonVersion: "3.5"
```

When you submit your job, point `gcloud` to that file, e.g.

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training --config=config.yaml ...
```

**Segfault**
This may be caused by running out of memory. Please check the memory usage in the console for that job. That said, if the job dies abruptly, memory usage at the time of failure may not be accurately reflected for that job.

Comment: Excellent re Python 3. Re segfault, I have by now found out that the model can't open the dataset file. It is still picking it up from a relative path, which worked outside Cloud ML, but apparently is not good practice with `gcloud ml-engine local train`. Maybe I'll post a follow-up question on this.

Comment: FYI: Follow-up question now posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47952143/does-google-cloud-ml-engine-trainer-has-to-be-explicitly-aware-of-google-cloud-s).