# Does Google Cloud ML Engine trainer have to be explicitly aware of Google Cloud Storage URIs?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to use an existing TensorFlow model, which I have so far run locally, with Google Cloud ML Engine.

The model currently obtains its training data by passing filesnames such as `my_model.train` and `my_model.eval` into [`tf.data.TextLineDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TextLineDataset).  These filenames are now hardcoded in the model's trainer, but I plan to refactor it such that it obtains them as [training application parameters](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/training-overview#params) (along with `--job-dir`) on the command line instead; e.g. like so:

```
my_trainer.pl --job-dir job \
  --filename-train my_model.train --filename-eval my_model.eval
```

This should then also allow me to run the trainer with Clould ML Engine locally:

```
gcloud ml-engine local train \
  --job-dir job
  ...
  -- \
  --filename-train my_model.train \
  --filename-eval my_model.eval
```

Am I making correct assumptions so far and could I also run the same trainer in Google's cloud (after uploading my dataset files into `my_bucket`) by replacing local filenames with Google Cloud Storage `gs:` URIs e.g. like so :

```
gcloud ml-engine local train \
  --job-dir job
  ...
  -- \
  --filename-train gs://my_bucket/my_model.train \
  --filename-eval gs://my_bucket/my_model.eval
```

I other worlds, can `tf.data.TextLineDataset` handle `gs:` URIs as "filenames" transparently, or do I have to include special code in my trainer for processing such URIs beforehand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, tf.read_file and tf.TextLineReader and tf.data.TextLineDataset all handle GCS implicitly.  Just make sure you pass in GCS URLs of the gs://my_bucket/path/to/data.csv as the "filename"

One thing to be careful about:  always use os.path.join() to combine "directory" names and "file" names.  While most Linux distributions handle paths like /some/path//somefile.txt by ignoring the repeated slash, GCS (being a key-value store) considers it different from /some/path/somefile.txt.  So, use os.path.join to make sure you are not repeating directory separators.

Comment: Thx. Note to self: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396552/google-storage-gs-wrapper-file-input-out-for-cloud-ml) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637685/1789384) on `tensorflow.python.lib.io.file_io` are related.