# Python version 3.6 not supported when running Cloud ML Engine trainer in the cloud

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I can by now run my TensorFlow model's trainer locally with Python 3.6  because [Cloud ML now supports Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47943960/1789384). However, if I try to run the same model in the cloud with `trainingInput.pythonVersion: "3.6"` in `config.yaml` I receive the following error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field: python_version Error: The specified Python version '3.6' is not supported.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: The specified Python version '3.6' is not supported.
    field: python_version
```

What can be done about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trainingInput.pythonVersion: "3.5"` (instead of `"3.6"`) apparently works.

I hope the fact that I am now runing Python 3.6 (`python -V`) locally, but Python 3.5 in the cloud won't cause subtle issues with Cloud ML Engine down the road.

Comment: You can see the full list of supported packages and versions at https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/runtime-version-list.

Comment: FYI I have by now installed Python 3.5 (next to Python 3.6) on my local development machine and am now using this (i.e. a single) version for running trainers both locally and in the cloud.

Comment: bummer 3.6 isn't supported. now i have to rewrite all my literal string interpolations